# Cant add sub query aliases in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys am new to mysql actually ...I am new understanding the concept of aliases..

When i have tried

```
(select 'kund' as mlech,'sdd' as sa);
```

it works just fine..It runs succesfully

But when i try to add subliases like

```
(select 'kund' as mlech,'sdd' as sa) as bab;
```

it throws me error like
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax`

Can you tell me why i cant add an alias for a sub query..

Thanks for the help..

Comment: If that is a sub-query, can you edit your post and add the rest of the query. Also the rest of the error would be helpful, it should have `... for the right syntax to use near 'something'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is fine if you are doing an actual subquery - you just need to use it as an actual subquery, ie:

`SELECT bab.* FROM (select 'kund' as mlech,'sdd' as sa) as bab;`

What you are doing is creating a derived table, and giving it the name 'bab'. It really only makes sense to do this in the context of referring to the results of that subquery, in another query.